# Choosing recepient of socket.send - Python socket module

Tags: python, sockets, chat

I am trying to make a group chat program, where an unlimited amount of clients may join the server using the same script, it'll work by the server receiving the clients message and sending it to all the connected clients including the sender. I have only managed to make it so that the sender only gets his own message back, but not what another client sends.

I was thinking of storing all the connected client IP's in a list, and sending it to each IP, but I do not know how to change the recpient of socket.send

Server code:

```
from threading import *
import socket

s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1337
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print("Server host is", host)


def getMainThread():
    for thread in enumerate(): 
        if thread.name == 'MainThread':
            return thread
    return None


class client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, address):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        main = getMainThread()
        while main and main.isAlive():
            print(self.address, "has connected!")
            message = self.socket.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
            self.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))

        self.socket.close()

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    client(c, addr)
    clients = [] #list for all client IP's
    clients.append(addr)
```

Also, is there a way so that the client can establish a connection with the server so it doesn't keep poping up on the server.py that client has connected each time it sends a message?

Client code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys
host = '25.154.84.23'
print("""
=======================================================
=Welcome to Coder77's local internet messaging service=
=======================================================
The current soon to be encrypted server is {0}

You can enter the command /help for a list of commands available
""".format(host))
#username = input("Enter username: ")
username = 'Smile'
print("Now connecting to {0}....".format(host))


def printhelp():
    print("""
The following commands are in the current version of this program:
/clear to clear the screen
/username to change your username
/exit to exit
/help for a list of commands
""")


def main():
    global username
    global host
    sock = socket.socket()
    try:
        sock.connect((host, 1337))
        while True:
            message2 = input("{0}: ".format(username))
            message = ('{0}: {1}'.format(username,message2))

            if '/quit' in message:
                sys.exit()
            if '/clear' in message:
                os.system('cls')
            if '/help' in message:
                printhelp()
            if '/username' in message:
                username = input("What would you like as your new username? ")

            sock.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
            received = sock.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
            print(received)
    except socket.error:
        print("Host is unreachable")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#

**Corrected** Server code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
from threading import *
import socket

s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1337
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
print("Server host is", host)


def getMainThread():
    for thread in enumerate():  # Imported from threading
        if thread.name == 'MainThread':
            return thread
    return None


class Client(Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, address):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.address = address
        self.start()

    def run(self):
            main = getMainThread()
            print(self.address, "has connected!")
            while main and main.isAlive():
                message = self.socket.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
                print(message)
                self.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
                for each_client in clients:
                    each_client.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    this_client = Client(c, addr)
    clients = []
    clients.append(this_client)
```

The new code, adapted by gravetii is causing a lot of format errors. What happens now, is the user gets back what he sent, he does not get back what other users send and the user gets back what his previous message was, its terribly confusing. Please run the code, and you'll see as it's very hard to explain.

Example
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your server code, you are doing only a `self.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))`. How can you then expect the server to send the message to all the clients? To do that you would need to iterate through the list of clients and call the `send()` method on each of their sockets.

```
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    client(c, addr)
    clients = [] #list for all client IP's
    clients.append(addr)
```

In this code, you are creating a client object but never adding it to the list, then what's the point of creating one?
I think what you want is this:

```
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    this_client = client(c, addr)
    clients = [] #list for all client IP's
    clients.append(this_client)
```

Then, you can send the message to all the clients by modifying the relevant part of your server code:

```
def run(self):
        main = getMainThread()
        while main and main.isAlive():
            print(self.address, "has connected!")
            message = self.socket.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
            self.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
            for each_client in clients:
                each_client.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
```

Also, why are you closing the connection after sending just one message? I believe your intention is to send more than one message to the server, and in that case, you don't need to close the connection.

Also, it's a better idea to create a class with its name starting with an upper case letter. So you may want to use `Client` instead of `client` for the class name.

Now coming to the issue of the message popping up everytime a client says something in your `server.py`, look at the run() method for the `client` thread:

```
def run(self):
        main = getMainThread()
        while main and main.isAlive():
            print(self.address, "has connected!")
            message = self.socket.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
            self.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
```

The thread starts executing as soon as you create the `client` object, and so the first time when it connects to the server, it is right in showing that message. But then it's incorrect to place the `print(self.address, "has connected!")` in the `while` loop. So everytime the client says something, the server sends it back to the client and then the loop runs again, thus displaying the message back again. You need to modify it like so:

```
def run(self):
        print(self.address, "has connected!")
        main = getMainThread()
        while main and main.isAlive():
            message = self.socket.recv(8192).decode('utf-8')
            self.socket.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I've updated my post with the relevant infomation.